# Not able to see Usage History under Azure Service connection for yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, serviceconnection

**Background -**

I have created one multi-stage yaml pipeline which contains the stages - BUILD, DeployToDEV, DeployToUAT, DeployToPROD. For deployment to azure web services, I used deployment job in the stages. In those deployment jobs, I'm using separate Service connections for different stages.

**Issue -**

If I create the release using classic UI and used the Service connections, then I can see the Usage history of releases under Service Connections. But for multi-stage yaml pipeline in which I'm deploying the web apps through multiple stages, I can't see the entry of same under usage history of the service connection. Though these service connections are getting used by the deployment jobs of the stages. So how we can resolve this issue.